# How can I obtain the displayed value instead of actual value in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy, format

I have a cell containing a date ex. "05/11/09"
It is currently displayed as "11-MAY-09". How do I copy-paste or use VBA to get the string "11-MAY-09" into the cell next to it ( NOT "05/11/09")?

I can't figure it out other than piecing out the date pieces by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Format function.

```
Format("5/11/2009", "DD-MMM-YY")
```

This will return:

```
11-May-09
```

If case matters:

```
UCase(Format("5/11/2009", "DD-MMM-YY"))
```

returns:

```
11-MAY-09
```

Answer (score 18):

```
Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Text
```

Using the cell's .text instead of .value modifier will copy the text formatting instead of the raw date.

Chuck

Comment: An issue with `.Text` is that if the column of the source range is not wide enough, the text displayed will be "####...".  Using `Format()` doesn't have this issue. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76484321/how-can-i-concatenate-a-bold-text-date-and-time-into-a-specific-cell/76484547#76484547

Comment: Why are you commenting on a 14 year old answer?  Just for reputation?

Comment: Just because an answer is old doesn't mean it can't be improved. I'm commenting to add information that is missing from your answer. If you think this information is relevant, feel free to mention/address it in your answer and I'll gladly delete my comment(s).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use the TEXT function to format a date value to your liking.

The format string of "dd-mmm-yy" would format "05/11/09" as "11-MAY-09".

Answer (score 2):

"The same answer but with a different function (that has worked for me):

```
Public Function DisplayText(ByVal pRange As Range) As String  
  DisplayText = pRange.Text  
End Function
```

Just use `=DisplayText(A1)`. If you change the cell format this function will return the displayed text"

- cc: alvaroc

[How can I get the displayed value of a cell in MS Excel ( for text that was converted to dates)?](https://superuser.com/questions/678934/how-can-i-get-the-displayed-value-of-a-cell-in-ms-excel-for-text-that-was-conv)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub FormattedText()
    Dim r As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select cell", Type:=8)
    If r.Count <> 1 Or r Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveCell = "'" & r.Text

End Sub
```

It will put text of a selected cell (prompted) in the active cell.

Answer (score 1):

Low-tech but very easy way - paste it into Word, then copy back into Excel! Can take a while with a big file, however... buts works great for one-off uses!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on the cell and set the format as General. This will allow you to put something in without it being automatically formatted to something else.

To save yourself from copying and pasting you will also want to start by putting in the date you want and not formatting and then copying.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can do this:

```
Range("B2") = Range("A2")
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" 'Date as 10-Jun-2005
```

If you need to loop it then:

```
Range("B" & i) = Range("A"& i)
Range("B" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" 'Date as 10-Jun-2005
```

[Another way to do it.](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1865519.php)