# How can I concatenate a bold text, date and time into a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, number-formatting

Basically, I'm trying to concatenate a specific text (in bold format), the date and time informed in another worksheet into a specific cell.
This code below help me to do that:

```
Sub Atualizar_Abertura()
Dim LN7A As String, LN7B As String
LN7A = "Próximo comunicado:"
LN7B = Planilha3.Range("I3")
Range("D23").Value = LN7A & " " & LN7B
Range("D23").Font.Bold = False
Range("D23").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Len(LN7A)).Font.Bold = True
Planilha5.Rows("23").AutoFit
End Sub
```

And this is the result [image: result]

But the source cell has the NumberFormat "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM [BR]" to be shown as: [image: Planilha3.Range("I3")]

So, what I'm expecting is: Concatenate the text as it's already being done and Date/time with the NumberFormat that I used into the cell I3.
I exemplified in an image: [image: Expected result]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could try `LN7B = Planilha3.Range("I3").Text`

Comment: define the string variable `LN7B` as formatted cell content: `LN7B = Format(Planilha3.Range("I3"), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM ""[BR]""")`

Comment: Thank you everyone, the .Text saved my life, why I did not think on it? LoL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. Here's 3 of them:

### 1. Use `.Text`

> .Text gives you a string representing what is displayed on the screen
> for the cell. Using .Text is usually a bad idea because you could get
> #### [if the column is not wide enough to display the full text]

<sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)</sup>

You can use it to read from the cell like this:

`LN7B = Planilha3.Range("I3").Text`

### 2. Use `Format()` with hardcoded format string

As suggested by T.M. in the comments, you can use

`LN7B = Format(Planilha3.Range("I3"), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM ""[BR]""")`

That has the advantage of avoiding issues where you could have "####" appear instead of the real date, but the inconvenient is that if the formatting of the cell changes, the output won't change.

### 3. Use `Format()` that changes based on the cell's formatting

`LN7B = Format(Planilha3.Range("I3").Value2, Planilha3.Range("I3").NumberFormatLocal)`

By using this approach, you are always sure that you'll get the same custom formatting as the cell the value came from. Note that there might be exceptions with some built-in number format such as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839676/numberformat-sometimes-returns-the-wrong-value-with-dates-and-times).